# RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was set.

Tags: python, flask

Flaskでアプリケーションを作っています。

RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was set. Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.
とエラーが出ました。

なぜこのようなエラーが出るのでしょうか？必要なモジュールがインポートされていないのでしょうか？

Comment: まず、エラーが出たらそのエラーメッセージでググると良いと思います。ググルと http://thr3a.hatenablog.com/entry/20171106/1509973583 とかみつかります。

Comment: @tanalab2  ありがとうございます。`app.secret_key = 'super secret key'`　の箇所が原因のようですね・・・。secret keyの部分に書く秘密鍵の情報はどこにありますか？Flaskドキュメントや検索を見ましたが、見つからず。もしお分かりでしたらお願いします。

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#sessions の "How to generate good secret keys"が参考になると思います。

Answer (score 2):

app.secret_key = 'super secret key'　と書いてあったのが間違いでした